# How do I make pipeline 'fixed' or enumerate it eagerly?

Tags: powershell

I have a script:

```
gci Published | % {
    $dest = Join-Path Published "$_.%ReleaseNumber%.%build.number%.zip"
    Write-Host "Packing as $dest"
    Compress-Archive -Path $_ -CompressionLevel NoCompression -DestinationPath $dest
}
```

(This script is being run by TeamCity, and `%ReleaseNumber%.%build.number%` part is correctly replaced.)

It appears that after first iteration `gci` sees newly created item and returns it as a second element of the sequence.

Is it possible to make `gci` initially return all the items and only then pass them to pipeline? Is there any special syntax for it **besides introducing a variable to store the result of `gci` command?**

Comment: store the output from `gci Published` in a variable and then pipe that to `%` in a separate statement

Comment: ``````(…)``````

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks, man!